# JQuery: Set a variable with a selected option form a dropdown menu within an embed code

Tags: jquery

I am trying to define a variable which should be set from a dropdown question within a form.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
hbspt.forms.create({
    portalId: 'XXXX',
    formId: 'XXXXXX',
    inlineMessage: 'You are being redirected to the Application...',
    onFormSubmit: function($form){
        
        var district = $form.find('input[name="distrito"]').find(' :selected').val();
        setTimeout( function() {
            window.location.href = "http://emprenda.com?locality=" + encodeURIComponent(district);
}, 500 ); // Redirects to url with query string data from form fields after 1/2 second.
        
    }
});
</script>
```

It works perfectly with a field which is inputed text but when switching to a dropdown it provides "undefined"

I have narrowed it down to this line:

```
var district = $form.find('input[name="distrito"]').find(' :selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a leading space. `find(' :selected')` but why not just

`var district = $form.find('input[name=distrito]').val()`

Also you need to not submit the form

Normally done in an event handler with event.preventDefault()` but your hbspt does not seem to allow that in the code you use here

See here:

https://rschu.me/prevent-the-submit-of-any-hubspot-forms-after-a-successful-validation-5e1f230b14f1

Comment: https://emprenda.com?locality=undefined Seems that the input value is stll not recognized by the code. Weird is that the code you have suggested is actually the one the works for the non dropdown fields

Comment: I cannot tell you since you did not post any of the rendered form